# Scale resolution of image keeping point locations

Tags: java, math, scale, scaling, calc

Consider the point at coordinates `821, 435` on a `1920, 1017` pixel image, landing somewhere in the middle of it. Now, scale the image down to `1243, 633` pixels large. Obviously, our point is no longer at those coordinates, but scaled down along with the image. How would I calculate what the new point's coordinates would be?

For the following assume `originalX = 1920` & `newX = 1243` and that we're just solving for the first value `x` right now (eventually doing the scale for the `y`)

I've done `newX/originalX` to get `0.64739583` which I can use to do `originalX * 0.64739583` and get `1243`, indicating `newX` is `64.739583%` of `originalX`. Now, go back to our previous point's `x`, 821. The new point's `x` is expected to be `482`, except that `originalX * 0.64739583 = 531`. `482` is not `531`, so the points don't match up as they're expected to with a scaling % of `64.7`

What would be the correct calculation (if these described calculations are even wrong and that parts of the picture are scaling wrongly) to be able to get the new coordinates of the scaled point?

Some more examples of points before/after scaling:

- `old = {width=1920, x=1807, y=996}, new = {width=1280, x=1167, y=698}`
- `old = {width=1920, x=1178, y=814}, new = {width=1280, x=1138, y=516}`
- `old = {width=1920, x=5, y=831}, new = {width=1517, x=5, y=693}`

Comment: `x is expected to be 482` - is expected by whom?

Comment: @MBo the point is a specific spot of a GUI in the image that's in the direct center and slightly offset- it's a screenshot of a program. `x` being expected to be `482` is the result of changing the program's resolution (in this case taking it out of maximized), giving it a smaller resolution. `821` is the `x` before un-maximizing, `482` is after.

Answer (score 1):

Your math is wrong. You say, "The new point's x is expected to be 482, except that originalX * 0.64739583 = 531."
The new point's x is, in fact, 532 (rounded). You don't give information for why newPointX is expected to be 482, and originalX * 0.64739583 = 1243. As far as how you would, "calculate what the new point's coordinates," are, see the code below.

```
int originalX = 1920;
int originalY = 1017;

int newX = 1243;
int newY = 633;

double scaleX = (double)newX/originalX;
double scaleY = (double)newY/originalY;

Point originalPoint = new Point(821, 435);
```

Method:

```
Point calculateNewPoint(Point originalPoint, double pScaleX, double pScaleY) {

    return new Point((int)Math.round(pScaleX*originalPoint.x), (int)Math.round(pScaleY*originalPoint.y));
}
```

Which, taken from your first paragraph results in a returned point of (532, 271).

Answer (score 0):

If such positions really take place, then scaling is not linear like

```
NewX = X * NewWidth / OldWidth
```

Instead I see the next: There is no scaling but shifting of image while keeping central position

```
middle of 1920 = 960
960 - 821 = 139
middle of 1243 = 621
621 - 482 = 139 !
```

So transformation law looks like  (I cannot claim it for single example)

```
NewX = NewWidth/2 + (OldX - OldWidth/2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not a perfect fit but definitely a good try for the sample I provided. I added some more; I'm still clueless on it as well.

Comment: Could you show a pictures for these magic transformations? (Note the same difference with right edge in the first of new examples)

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar problem. I had a picture of 1920x1080 pixeles, and I want to reduce that picture an 1.3, then I want to know a point in the reduced picture, which position correspond that point in the original picture. I show a picture that I want to do.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8EqD.png)

Then, I got a reduced picture of 1477x831, since (1920/1.3, 1080/1.3). If a have a point in the original picture in the position (250,300), and I reduce the picture, the new point in the reduced picture, it will be in the position (192,231), since (250/1.3 , 300/1.3) is (192,231). Then, If I reduce the picture and I get the point (192,231) and I want to get the position in the original picture, I have only to do (192 x 1.3 ,231 x 1.3) is (250,300). We can use the factor of scaled that we want prefer, I have use 1.3, but we can use 2, to reduce the picture to half.

I share the code.

```
private double factorScale = 1.3;
    
private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
            int x = evt.getX(); // x = 192
            int y = evt.getY(); // y = 231
            int xWithOutScaled = (int) (factorScale  * x); // xWithOutScaled = 250
            int yWithOutScaled = (int) (factorScale * y); //  yWithOutScaled = 300
        }

    private void printImage(int positionImage) {
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = null;
            File file = new File[pathImage];
            try{
                image = ImageIO.read(file); 
            }catch(IOException ie){
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error reading image file","Error",javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            int widthScaled = (int) (width / factorScale); // widthScaled= 1477 ,width = 1920
            int heightScaled = (int) (height / factorScale); // heightScaled=831 ,height = 1080
            Image img = image.getScaledInstance(widthScaled,heightScaled,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
            this.image.setIcon(newIcon);                                        
        }
```

In your case, you have to calculate the factor scaled, that it is (1920/1243) = 1.54 and (1017/633)=1.60, In your case, the proportion is no the same in x an y because the size of the reduced image chosen, but if we only do in the x. The point in the original picture in the position 821, it is in the position 533 (821/1.54) in the reduced picture. In the same way, we can calculate the position in the original picture (533* x 1.54) is 821.